# "Off-label use" of Mathematica functions for performance

Tags: functions, performance-tuning

Assisting an acquaintance with a simulation where a very large number of binomial probability calculations are required, I pointed them to a slightly obscure function to dramatically speed up their algorithm. Specifically, for

```
Probability[x == b, x \[Distributed] BinomialDistribution[n, p]]
```

the same result can be had with

```
BernsteinBasis[n, b, p]
```

but the latter is 15-20X faster (and surprisingly generally more accurate with inexact *p*) than the former, and 1.5-2X faster than *PDF* calculation. Only explicit calculation using the formula for binomial probability is faster.

I'm curious what other "off-label" uses of built-in functions have been noted to have performance advantages.

Comment: Please define "acquaintance"

Comment: @belisarius: Only the names have been changed to protect the innocent...

Comment: Actually, for large n and d (e.g, 4000 and 3000, p=0.5) the PDF calculation is faster than the BernsteinBasis calculation.